# How do I create application scope variable django?

Tags: django

How can I create an application scope variable which is loaded when the django app starts, be in memory and accessible by all.

Basically I want to reuse the variable through out the application without reloading it.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could add it to your `settings.py` file.  Or, add it to the `__init__.py` file inside the app directory.

Answer (score 3):

Are you referring to something like an environment variable?  You could load it via init...

```
__init__.py

import os
os.environ['APP_VAR_WHATEVER'] = 'hello world!'
```

Answer (score 2):

Python has three levels of namespace — local (specific to the current function or class method), global (specific to the current module), and built-in. That is, Python does not really have project-wide global variables.

If it's a read-only variable you want, you could use `settings.py` to define the value and `import settings` from all other modules that want access to the variable.

If it for both reading and writing, I would likely use the database backend I'm already using with Django, instead of a python variable.

If you could provide a more detailed description of what you're trying to achieve, perhaps we could come up with a better suited solution.

Comment: I guess the problem is that a variable in settings.py is in project-scope. To have a variable for app a settings file inside the app or possibly definition in __init__.py of the app might work.

Comment: got the underscores removed from around init

Comment: Actually I want to load a heavy array from the database (skipping  direct db call)

Comment: For your next question, I recommend including that kind of information in order to help the people answering.

I would likely have used memcache in your situation.