# Shared global variables among apps

Tags: django

Suppose I have two apps: `data` and `visual`.
App `data` executes a database retrieval upon starting up. This thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6791911/execute-code-when-django-starts-once-only) and [this doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.ready) advises on how and where to place code that executes once on starting up. So, in app `data`:

```
#apps.py

from django.apps import AppConfig

global_df    #want to declare a global variable to be shared across all apps here.

class DataConfig(AppConfig):
    # ...

    def ready(self):
        from .models import MyModel
        
        ...
        df = retrieve_db()   #retrieve model instances from database

        ...
        return df
```

In the code above, I am looking to execute `ready()` once on starting up and return `df` to a shared global variable (in this case, `global_df`). App `visual` should be able to access (through `import`, maybe) this `global_df`. But, any further modification of this `global_df` should be done only in app `data`.

This thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1781400/how-do-i-create-application-scope-variable-django) advised to place any global variable in the app's `__init__.py` file. But it mentioned that this only works for `environmental variable`.

Two questions:

1 - How and where do I declare such a global variable?

2 - On starting up, how to pass the output of a function that executes only once to this global variable?

Some threads discuss Redis for caching purpose. But I am not looking for that solution as it seems like an overkill for the problem I am having.